# socket.io 1.1 - connecting

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Migrating from 0.9 to 1.1.

In our previous version we were checking to see if socket was connecting using socket.socket.connecting.

What would be the equivalent of this for 1.1? Connecting seems to no longer be present.

Thank-you

Comment: Try `socket.connected`

Comment: Thanks, but we check connected AND connecting. Connected is still there in 1.1.

Comment: Just `socket.connected` and not `socket.socket.connected`, right?

Comment: Yes that is right. socket.connected is present and working in 1.1

But not connecting...

Comment: There's a [`socket.on('connecting', function () {})`](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events)